# Is there a way I can use multiple DBspaces for one single database?

Tags: informix

I am trying to load one extracted Informix database with `dbimport` command and unfortunately the IBM Informix Demo Version have been exceeded after adding 8 GB of chunks to my current DBspace. I'm wondering if there is way I can combine two or more DBspaces to load my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including more information on the version of Informix would help as different versions may have different restrictions on usage and implement these restrictions in different ways. For example in 14.10.xC1 the IBM Informix Developer Edition (there is no "Demo" edition) limits the storage to 8 GB. This is a limit on the overall storage for the instance and not per dbspace.

Moving on from any storage restrictions imposed by the Informix edition the `dbimport` command only provides a command-line option to set the dbspace used for the entire database. If you are importing from a directory, as opposed to a tape device, then you can edit the schema sql file contained within that directory to set the storage options for each create table or create index statement. These options can include using a specific dbspace for storage or enabling fragmentation to use multiple dbspaces for the larger tables. I would recommend testing the modified schema file using `dbaccess` before using it with `dbimport` so that you can catch any syntax errors etc.